# commas with asyndeton (series without 'and') at beginning of sentence

Tags: commas, compound-subjects, asyndeton

We don't put a comma between a subject and verb phrase, even with a series:

> My Dad, my sister, and my brother came home together.

What about after a series that is an asyndeton, where the 'and' is omitted?

> My Dad, my sister, my brother, came home together. [with comma]
>   My Dad, my sister, my brother came home together. [without comma]

I am editing an old text with lots of these, some quite complex. We don't want to change the writer's style. I started removing the comma before the verb phrase, but then with the complex ones, it seems to need a comma, e.g.:

> The reading of holy scriptures, torturing the body in various ways, donning robes of various colours, running away from one’s duties and obligations, seeking the seclusion of forest retreats and mountains, can never bring salvation.

Should the comma before 'can' be omitted?

Comment: The best I can suggest is to insert an ellipsis before the verb with weightier subjects, You can add an explanation of how and why you are making these changes (just cut and paste the body text!) Inserting << ... these >> in your last example works, but may be seen as too great a style adjustment. // I don't see how the less weighty << My Dad, my sister, my brother came home together. >> really works. There's _possibly_ justifying context for omitting 'and', but I'd need the ellipsis-length pause for consideration.

Comment: There are loads of these in the text - it's a summary of a discourse where this was the speaker's style. It seems lots of ellipses might be strange. What about this? The reading of holy scriptures, torturing the body in various ways, donning robes of various colours, running away from one’s duties and obligations, seeking the seclusion of forest retreats and mountains - all these can never bring salvation.

Comment: (a) I think you're stuck with preserving the original punctuation then, with a note about how modern adjustments (with examples) look less archaic but don't really do justice to the originals. Unless you think the originals were rather idiosyncratic even for their time, in which case altering punctuation might be an obvious improvement. / (b) If you make a change to the wording, I'd suggest '... none of these can ...'. _Salvation by works!!_

Comment: Thanks, excellent advice. I may add a few 'and's. And modify a few as suggested.

Comment: Remember to explain clearly how and why you've made adjustments. _And keep checking for heresies ... er, slips._

Comment: @msarajevo The writer seems, perhaps, to have forgotten the text : _the holy scriptures ... are able to make thee wise unto salvation_. II Timothy 3:15.

Comment: Ah, maybe it should be added - all these *alone* can never bring salvation!